# starting a listener in ruby

Tags: ruby, listener

I'm trying to implement a listener in ruby, i'm using this code:

```
get '/listener' do
 rd = Round.where(_id: '****').first
 rd.listener
 redirect '/'
end
```

and i have a listener method on my Round class:

```
def listener
listener = Listen.to('/folder1/folder2', :filter => /\.rb$/, :ignore => %r{ignored/path/}) do |modified, added, removed|
  puts 'message here'
end
listener.start 
end
```

this code worked fine the first few times when i call the /listener address, it starts my listener and every time i modify, add or remove a file in folder1/folder2 i see the message.
Now the same code stops my ruby server when i call the /listener address when it gets to the listener.start on my listener method. And there is no error to be shown, it just stops my application.
I read that adding a "sleep" after the listener.start could be a solution, but i already tried it and i had the same result.

Comment: What are you running?  Sinatra?  Also why do you have a web request starting up this potentially long running listener?

Comment: yes i'm running Sinatra, and i'm using a web request because i'm just testing for now.